Is it possible to merge a referenced query to it's source query in Power Query (Power Bi)?
Power Query doesn't let me merge a query to it's source query.

I tried merging both tables but the reference table doesn't show up as an option of tables to be joined.
The referenced query is a summary table (using Power Query Group By) and I want to join this back to the main table.
I'm basically trying to perform the SQL equivalent of a SUM window function, like:
SUM(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY dept_id) AS dept_total_salary
Thank you

you can merge to the same query or any other query. Easiest is to copy the query you want to merge to a separate temporary query then manually edit the code to instead point to a previous step or a different query

You can also do this in the Advanced Editor. But you'd need to familiarize yourself with writing M-Code.
